# Objective-C - Parsing a .csv, extracting and inserting information, then displaying the .csv as an interface for editing

Tags: html, objective-c, arrays, parsing, csv

This question has been troubling me for the past week. Below, I will list my issue, and the research I have put into it.

**The scenario:** I was given a .csv file with 5000 rows and three columns. The three columns are defined as:

Site ID|Site Name|Site URL

**My task:** To create an HTML interface for the designers of the company to rate each site on a scale of 1-5.

**My plan of action:** I am a new hire. I am getting accustomed to the language I was hired for, which was Objective-C.

My algorithm for the project was to:

1. Parse the .csv
2. Remove the "Site Name" variable
3. Create a new .csv that contains the below variables: Site ID|Site URL|Rating|Image
4. Display the new .csv (with all aforementioned items) as an HTML page where there are toggles for "Ratings", which when pressed, will log the rating into the .csv which it was imported (or loaded) from.

The "Image" section I will be using a piece of software by the name of Paparazzi (on the Mac OS X operating system) which takes a fully formatted screenshot of the main page and saves it as a PNG file. I plan on using the file extension URL (which is stored locally) and load it into the "Image" column, thus when the designer clicks on the image, he is able to load the image that is stored locally.

**My issue:** As Objective-C is not entirely a scripting language, I am confused with some of the libraries I may need and/or methods I can implement this. I have the algorithm, but I am wholy unsure with the implementation.

**My questions:** If you have done a project similar to this before with Objective-C, what tips can you provide for me? How does one load the .csv as a HTML interface where upon edit, it will save this edit into the .csv? Will I need any servers for this, or is everything executable from just a machine? How do you grab an image (stored locally), extract its file extension, and load it onto the .csv?

The most important question: Is this achievable through Objective-C? My reasoning behind it is, I want to advance my knowledge of OC through a task like this. Yes, using Python is easier, but is it possible to do this with Objective-C?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It certainly is achievable, but I doubt you'd really want to go this way. If I understand it correctly, you want to serve the HTML page to others via web browser - that would mean either writing a (simple) http daemon, that would run on the server or writing a CGI script that would communicate with a standard http daemon. Python/PHP/Ruby do this for you readily, so there is much less room for possible errors.

As for

> As Objective-C is not entirely a scripting language

I would perhaps rephrase it as

> As Objective-C is entirely not a scripting language

Comment: Thank you. That was very funny.

If I were to approach this task through Python, do you think my approach is correct? What are some good resources for a task like this? 

Thanks Peter!

Comment: @faroskalin I would say either of the Python/Ruby/PHP/Perl combo is fine. creating the html is more or less a matter of a single regular expression plus some headers, turning it back into csv is not much more difficult, if you want to do this per user (i.e. each of the designers will produce one csv and those will be merged later independently). Otherwise you'd probably want to record the answers into a database (might not be a bad idea anyway, it would just be a bit more work).